# Proper resistor for simple circuit

Tags: batteries, resistance, ohms-law

I have a potentially stupid question, but I have no idea how to handle the problem. I want to use 9V battery with a diode that requires 5V. So I need a resistor. How do I find the resistance if (as far as I managed to find out) it is improper to speak about the current in therms of batteries. So  have two unknowns in Ohms law: required resistance and current. All I have is potential.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A diode that requires 5V is presumably a Zener diode.  Zener diodes are designed to maintain a reasonably constant voltage as the current through them varies.  They are usually used to provide a constant voltage to power other circuit elements. It is necessary to  have a resistor in series with a Zener diode to control the current.  Normally a Zener diode is rated to have a certain current through it to be able to maintain a constant voltage.  You need to know this current plus the current to be drawn into the following circuit to select the required resistor.  For example, if the Zener diode needs 10 ma to work properly, and the following circuit requires 20 ma, then the supply feeding the diode must provide 30 ma. In your example, with a 9V battery as the source, the resistor must drop 9V-5V or 4V while conducting 30 ma.  Thus the value of the resistor should be 4/0.03 or 133 ohms.

Comment: Thanks, you cleared to me this quite well. And what if there was lets say only a bulb and resistor with no diode and a circuit?

Comment: well that then depends on the maximum current your bulb can support.